# Why am I getting a 429 response from the Steam API?

Tags: python, request, steam

I've been trying to use the Steam inventory API in Python, and I'm getting a 429 response.

I understand that this means I'm being rate limited, but I've waited at least 30 minutes between requests only to get the same response. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import requests
link = "http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/STEAMID/APPID/2?l=english&count=2000"
print(requests.get(link).json())
```

My first few requests returned the data I was looking for, but every request since, seemingly no matter the wait between them, returns the 429 code. I've looked around online and the usual thing people say is that you can query this endpoint 5 times per minute, which is infinitely more than I am able to achieve.

Can anyone provide some insight into why I'm observing this behaviour?

Comment: Is the code running in a shared IP address namespace (cloud, firewall, proxy, etc) where other programs might also be using this api?

Comment: @JohnGordon the code is part of a Flask app that I'm running locally on my PC at home. I expect this program to be the only thing calling this API from my PC

Comment: Do you use a large internet service provider?  It's possible that other customers of your ISP are also using this api, and the api is treating them all as one caller, since the IP addresses are similar (although not exactly the same).  Yes, this is a long shot, but it's the only actual explanation I can think of...

Comment: @JohnGordon I suppose this is the only reasonable explanation. Thanks for your help!